# Python: Write Pandas Dataframe to MSSQL --> Database Error

Tags: python, sql-server, database, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that has about 20k rows and 20 columns.  I want to write it to a table in MSSQL.

I have the connection successfully established:

```
connection = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};' 
                              'Server=XXX;' 
                              'Database=line;' 
                              'uid=XXX;' 
                              'pwd=XXX')

cursor = connection.cursor()
```

I'm trying to write my pandas dataframe to the MSSQL server with the following code:

```
df_EVENT5_16.to_sql('MODREPORT', connection, if_exists = 'replace')
```

But I get the following error:

> DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master
>   WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC
>   SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'sqlite_master'.")

Comment: You need to use [SQLAlchemy connection](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mssql.html) for `to_sql` and not your raw DB-API connection.

Comment: Also, `pypyodbc` may not have an alchemy layer but `pyodbc` does.

Answer (score 12):

Modern Pandas versions expect [`SQLAlchemy engine`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#microsoft-sql-server) as a connection, so use SQLAlchemy:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

con = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://username:password@myhost:port/databasename?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+10.0')
```

and then:

```
df_EVENT5_16.to_sql('MODREPORT', con, if_exists='replace')
```

from [DataFrame.to_sql() docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html):

> **con** : SQLAlchemy engine or DBAPI2 connection (legacy mode)
>
> Using SQLAlchemy makes it possible to use any DB supported by that library.
>
> If a DBAPI2 object, only sqlite3 is supported.

Comment: thank you .. do I need to pip install sql alchemy first?  Also, after your 'mssql+pyodbc' statement ... is it: what is scott? what is tiger? what is mydsn?

Comment: @PineNuts0, you may want to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41729710/5741205)

Answer (score 3):

No need to use pyodbc to connect with MSSQL, SQL Alchemy will do that for you. 
And also we can insert the data-frame directly into the database without iterating the data-frame using to_sql() method. Here is the code that working fine for me -

```
# To insert data frame into MS SQL database without iterate the data-frame
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table, select
from six.moves import urllib
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={SQL 
Server};SERVER=serverName;DATABASE=dbName;UID=UserName;PWD=password")
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params) 
engine.connect() 
# suppose df is the data-frame that we want to insert in database
df.to_sql(name='table_name',con=engine, index=False, if_exists='append')
```