# Unable to write a dataframe to SQL Server as a table using SQL Alchemy, connection is established but cannot write a new table to the database

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I can connect to SQL Server using SQLAlchemy, but I am not able to write the data frame to the database as a table.

I am getting the below error:

```
try:
SqlServerEngine = pyodbc.connect(driver='{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}', 
                            host=server_name, 
                            database=database_name,
                            trusted_connection=tcon)

result = SqlServerEngine.execute('SELECT 1')
for row in result:
    print(row)
print("SQL Server connection established successfully.")  
    
App_test.to_sql('App_test', 
                        schema='Test_Data', 
                        con=SqlServerEngine, 
                        if_exists='replace', 
                        index=False)

# Close the database connection
SqlServerEngine.close()
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")
```

Output as below:

```
(1, )
SQL Server connection established successfully.
Error: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'sqlite_master'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW); [42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: `SELECT name FROM sqlite_master` - something seems to think you are connecting to SQLite rather than SQL Server.

Comment: Aside... you really should not be using the `{SQL Server}` driver any more. This was the old, unsupported and no longer distributed "SQL Server Native Client" driver that was Windows-only and has not seen any feature updates since SQL Server 2012 days.  New applications should be using `{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}` or `{ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}` depending on which version you have installed, and are also available for macOS and multiple flavours of Linux, ref: [Download ODBC Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, thank you for the note, I made changes, nevertheless, the error remains:
Error: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'sqlite_master'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW); [42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")

Comment: We clearly can't see enough code to assist you, because somewhere it thinks you are using SQLite.

Comment: And if you have changed the code which you are using, you need to update your question to include that code.

Comment: Have you read the [pandas.DataFrame.to_sql documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) yet? The `con` parameter is expected to be an instance of `sqlalchemy.engine.Engine` or `sqlalchemy.engine.Connection`. Have you tried passing in one of those instead of a pyodbc `Connection`?

Comment: This has been answered before:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48154172/python-write-pandas-dataframe-to-mssql-database-error